# AngularJS: Highly Dynamic Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, controllers, angularjs-routing

**Hi,**

I am currently looking to implement something like this (**AngularJS**):

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/root/:controllerName/blah/:blahId/blah/:blah', {
        templateUrl: '/tmpl/:controllerName/blah/partials/:blah' + '.html',
        controller: ':controllerName' + 'Ctrl'
    })
```

This is probably overly complicated (with the 'blah, blah, blah') but I wanted to make sure it is clear.

In a nutshell, I'm aiming to accomplish something similar (enough) to how **Microsoft MVC employs their routing to controllers** -- in other words, very autonomous:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

After that, I intend to LazyLoad the controller (which I have already), but this needs to be (hopefully) compatible with LazyLoading.

Has anyone had success with this approach, know of any resources, or have any ideas about how to accomplish this?

--PreThanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you will be able to resolve this using **ngRoute** but I think **ngInclude** should be able to help:

**Html**

```
<div class="slide-animate-container">
    <div ng-include="template.url"></div>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.template.url = "";//some dynamic rules
```

Here is a link to angular documentation on this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: Thx Dalorzo, I've been using `when('...', template: '<div ng-include="'/r/o/u/t/e/{{view}}'" ="" ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>', controller: 'WhateverCtrl', controllerAs: 'MyCtrl')`, where a resolver loads the `:controller` and aliases it under `'MyCtrl'` -- but I would like to be able to do an entire 'pre-config' of the `.when(...)` and have Angular `$interpolate` the `templateUrl` and require a controller (and call a delegate to fetch styles conditionally). Thanks for the input, Dalorzo :)