# AngularJS route doesn't work if its inserted as new address

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I create a simple angularjs app.

this is my config:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        controller: "homeController",
        templateUrl: "/views/home.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
        controller: "loginController",
        templateUrl: "/views/login.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" }); // or notfound.html
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

and in my `index.html`

```
<base href="/">
```

when I start web site from `index.html` (localhost/index.html) file everything is fine. the url change to `localhost/home` or `localhost/login` and everythings work.

but when I use the **home** or **login** url I get 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the server involved to handle 404 errors.

`http://localhost/home` when asked by the browser looks up the home path on you server or home.html when it isn't found you get the 404

When you select a link within angular app it will load index.html (the app) and route to `#/home` then re-address it to `/home`

You can set up your server to route all traffic to `/` and let the app handle routing.

look here for a similar solution.
[AngularJS Dynamic Routes Without Hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789399/angularjs-dynamic-routes-without-hashtag?rq=1)

**edit**

redirect 404 to main index [Configuring custom ASP 404 page with redirect for IIS7 website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016933/configuring-custom-asp-404-page-with-redirect-for-iis7-website)

Comment: how can i set this in iis or iis express?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running without a web server, you will need to prefix your links with the `#` sign.

```
<a href="#/login">
```

[AngularJS routing without a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677882/angularjs-routing-without-a-web-server)

Comment: first my link works. its when user insert url themself in browser. second when I type `localhost/#login` it works. nice suggestion. but not what I want

Comment: @Raika I dont think it's possible to do what you're asking for. Remember that AngularJS is a client-side framework, doing it's job in JavaScript in the client browser. There's no actual server involved unless you install one.